# How to disable ion-fab button?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have fab-button as below and I want to disable it if form is not valid, but based on docs at http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/fab/FabButton/ it seems fab-button doesn't have `disabled` property.

```
<ion-fab right bottom [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">
    <button ion-fab color="primary"><ion-icon name="md-checkmark"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-fab>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to disable the button inside the `ion-fab`. This code works for me:

```
<ion-fab bottom right>
  <button ion-fab [disabled]="!isValidInput()" (click)="add()">
    <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-fab>
```

Answer (score 1):

You did absolutely fine but sometimes some property is not applicable to some element.

So here you can't apply disabled directly on the ion-fab attribute.

So, just cut + paste disabled from ion-fab to button.

```
<ion-fab right bottom>
    <button ion-fab color="primary" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid"><ion-icon name="md-checkmark"></ion-icon></button>
</ion-fab>
```